# how to evaluate consistency of rankings for n columns

Tags: hypothesis-testing, ranks

Suppose I have `n` columns in a matrix (example below has `n= 4`).

Is there a test I can check that the rankings over columns are the same? Specifically, if the rankings in column 1 are "similar" to that of column 2, etc etc..

For two columns I can possibly do something like the morisita index but I need n columns and a p-value hopefully.

Thanks!

```
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
 [1,]    5   42   17   46
 [2,]   39   49   16   17
 [3,]   46   28   21   26
 [4,]   17    3   28    5
 [5,]   40   45   46   25
 [6,]   13   11    7   11
 [7,]   25    8   32   13
 [8,]   47   18    6   43
 [9,]   37   16   25   22
[10,]   41   17   12   34
[11,]    8   26   24   36
[12,]    1    5   34   28
[13,]   21   46   48   14
[14,]   34   35   37   10
[15,]   24    9   49   39
[16,]    3   41   31    3
[17,]   43   19   36   18
[18,]   42   48   15   37
[19,]   36   37   43   30
[20,]   30   31   10   45
[21,]   26   29   30   50
[22,]   20   43   11   31
[23,]   14   13   45   33
[24,]    4   21    9   49
[25,]   23   34    1   12
[26,]   33   20   42   48
[27,]   31   10   26    9
[28,]   11   12   29   21
[29,]   48    6   22   41
[30,]   12    2    5   16
[31,]    7   27   38    2
[32,]   19   15    8    7
[33,]   44    1    3    6
[34,]   49   24   13   44
[35,]   29   47   41   15
[36,]   27   30   44    1
[37,]    9   32   20   24
[38,]   10   25   23   47
[39,]   50   22   27   27
[40,]   16   39   35   38
[41,]   35    7   18    8
[42,]    2    4    4   29
[43,]   28   50   33   35
[44,]    6   33   14   40
[45,]   38   40   50   19
[46,]   18   38   40   20
[47,]   22   23   19   42
[48,]   15   36   39   32
[49,]   45   44    2   23
[50,]   32   14   47    4
```

Answer (score 0):

This rank-based procedure has been recommended as being robust to non-normal errors, resistant to outliers, and highly efficient for many distributions. It may result in a known statistic (e.g., in the two independent samples layout ranking)

In this problem i suggest you to run the test in the **Wilcoxon rank-sum / Mann–Whitney U test**

Comment: This just looks at 2 related samples. Then I would have to do all pairwise comparisons..

Comment: Isn't that what you are asking for in the question?

Comment: @user1357015 if you wanna do for n columns just run the kruskal-Wallis H test for several n independent column.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that Kendall’s *W* (Kendall’s coefficient of concordance) may work for this problem.  This statistic is related to Friedman's test (which supplies a *p* value).  I don't know if it has any relation to the Morisita index.